# How to fetch the content displayed in JAVA applet?

Tags: java, applet, japplet

When I hit the following web page, my required document is opened in a JAVA Applet:
http://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/DocumentImageView?doc_id=2004111600528001

I want to download the document which opens in the applet, the document could be of multiple pages. Is there a way to communicate with applet and fetch its content?

Comment: Apparently the `TIFFView` applet merely finds the relevant TIFF files in the web server's directories. Decompile the JAR to view the URL generation logic for each document page.

Comment: So how I can download the JAR from website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a tool named [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).
*"Fiddler is a free web debugging proxy which logs all HTTP(s) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Use it to debug traffic from virtually any application that supports a proxy like IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, and more."*

So when I opened the web page and document loaded in applet, Fiddler captured the internal requests made by applet to server which I was unable to see in browser and from there I got the direct URL to that document which I then used to download it :)